# Mkdir() is not working in Android Realme device?

Tags: java, android

Hello masters i had tested my old phone, code working fine but same code tried to run in Realme Device mkDir() is not work

my code

```
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ok";
                File dir = new File(fullPath);
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdir();
```

get error in cosole

```
2021-03-01 04:06:10.794 5444-5498/? E/SubscriptionManagerWrapper: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.telephony.SubscriptionManager.getActiveDataSubscriptionId []
2021-03-01 04:06:10.943 893-16766/? E/lsc_nvram: [do_mkdir] fail to mkdir [/sdcard/shading_otp]: 13[Permission denied] (do_mkdir){#65:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/isp_40/lsc_mgr/LscUtil.h}
2021-03-01 04:06:11.943 893-16766/? E/lsc_nvram: [do_mkdir] fail to mkdir [/sdcard/shading_otp]: 13[Permission denied] (do_mkdir){#65:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/isp_40/lsc_mgr/LscUtil.h}
2021-03-01 04:06:12.944 893-16766/? E/lsc_nvram: [do_mkdir] fail to mkdir [/sdcard/shading_otp]: 13[Permission denied] (do_mkdir){#65:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/isp_40/lsc_mgr/LscUtil.h}
```

what I had tried

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You will not have write access to that location on Android 11 and higher. Please use something else. For example, if you use `getExternalFilesDir(null)` on `Context`, you get a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) that you can read and write, without permissions.

Comment: `if (!dir.exists())
                    if(!dir.mkdir()) return;` Display a Toast too to inform the user. Which Android version?

Comment: `what I had tried` That is not enough: runtime permissions.